# Html5 audio / jQuery : playback latency issue (preload)

Tags: jquery, html

I am working with html5 audio and running into some troubles with the buffer. This works splendidly in Chrome, however in Safari (and SafMob) there is noticeable latency. The idea is simple. A user clicks an img link and the img "jumps" and makes a sound. [Here is an example](http://superuntitled.com/development/sound.html).

Is there a way to preload the sound file so that it plays quicker? Again, my main concern is in the Safari/Safari Mobile browser.

The jQuery I am using:

```
$("#bell a").click(function() {
  var snd = new Audio("ping.mp3");
  snd.play();
  $(this).stop().animate({ marginTop: "-10px" }, 200).animate({ marginTop: "18px" }, 200).animate({ marginTop: "1px" }, 300); 
return false;
});
```

This is the code for the button:

```
<ul id="bell">
  <li class="button"><a href="#" title="Pling">Link Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

preload actually takes a value, one of auto, meta or automatic. Although I think the default behaviour is to download the entire file.

There's a bit more at: [Playing with audio files](http://www.html5laboratory.com/playing-with-audio-files.php) or from the specification itself: [preload attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#attr-media-preload).

Not sure if this helps at all.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid creating a new Audio element each time you click by having it on a global variable, so you reuse the existing instance.

Then replace `snd.play();` with `snd.cloneNode(true).play();`

For me it made a huge difference.